Laravel: Starting a download and displaying a Flash message in the blade at the same time
How can you do it when a user makes a request to start a download and at the same time send him a flash message?
A. Flash message (example):
return redirect()->route('success')->with('success', 'hello');
B. Start download (example):
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::download($path);
C. Example which does not work. But it should be a mix of both examples from above:
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::download($path)->with('success', 'hello');

You can't do that straight from the server side you'd need some client-side tricks to get this to work

As far as I know, HTTP responses are singular operations. It means you can't download and return messages at the same time.
But you can archive this by First sending a Flash message and then downloading.

In your web route, add this
Route::get('/download-file', function () {
    $path = 'path/to/your/file.pdf';
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::download($path);
})->name('download.file'); 

When you click the "download button", show the download page with this as a return.
return redirect()->route('show.download.page')->with('success', 'file is ready to download!');

In that view, add like this.
<body>
@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        window.location.href = "{{ route('download.file') }}";
    }
</script>
</body>


Hello Abdulla! Thank you for your detailed and understandable answer.
